# Split string in portions base on values in database

Tags: c#, database, split

For my company I am writing an addin for Autodesk Inventor to make sure certain properties of a document are filled in. One of these properties is called description. After writing a value to that property, the addin has to read the value storen in there and show it to the user in a form. But, when the description is created by the user, the user has to choose from a list of values, stored in a database.

There are three database:
TblPrefix:

```
| ID | PrefixName    | Prefix |
|----|---------------|--------|
| 1  | System Layout | SL     |
| 2  | Sub Assembly  | MS     |
```

TblDescription1 & TblDescription2:

```
| ID | Description    | Abbreviation |
|----|--------------- |--------------|
| 1  | Acces & Egress | A&E          |
| 2  | Building       | *null*       |
| 3  | West           | W            |
| 4  | Infeed         | *null*       |
| 5  | Column Grid    | *null*       |
```

The description is constructed by Prefix + *underscore* + Description1 + Description2 + FreeText. An example would be SL_Column Grid West XXX, where

- Prefix = SL (choosen from database)
- Description1 = Column Grid (choosen from database)
- Description2 = West (choosen from database)
- FreeText = XXX

My question is now how to split the value (SL_Column Grid West XXX) into the appropriate parts? To make it even more complicated, some descriptions have an abbreviation. So West could also be W, Conveyor could be CNV, etc. On the form always the full description name is visible as is the prefix name, never the abbreviation.

At this point I am able to read the prefix, underscore and the first description/abbreviation. I don't know how to find the second description and the free text.

```
//Read Description
            string txtDescription = readProperties.ReadDesignProperty("Description", oDoc).ToString();

            //try to read the description stored in the iProperty,
            //if empty set strings for the description to empty
            try
            {
                //split description at underscore
                string[] description = txtDescription.Split(new string[] { "_" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                string prefix = description[0];
                string descriptionText = description[1];
                string firstWordDescription1 = Regex.Match(descriptionText, @"^([\w\-]+)").Value;

                //get prefix name from database
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select PrefixName from TblPrefix Where Prefix = '" + prefix + "'", con);
                prefix = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                //try to get the first part of the description
                cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Description from TblDescription1 Where Description Like '%" + firstWordDescription1 + "%'", con);
                string description1 = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                //if the first part of the description is an abbrevation, get the description name from the database
                //and set the description preview to use the abbreviation
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(description1))
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Description from TblDescription1 Where Abbreviation Like '%" + firstWordDescription1 + "%'", con);
                    description1 = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                    abbreviation1 = true;

                }

                con.Close();

                comboBoxPrefix.SelectedIndex = comboBoxPrefix.FindStringExact(prefix);
                comboBoxDescription1.SelectedIndex = comboBoxDescription1.FindStringExact(description1);
            }
            catch
            {
                string prefix = string.Empty;
                string description1 = string.Empty;
                string description2 = string.Empty;
            }

            labelDescription.Text = CreateDescription();
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail of sample data, like what would freetext look like?

Comment: if you already found the 1st desc, use substring to trim them off, then repeat the same for the 2nd desc. Any difficulty there?

Comment: [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)

Comment: @AliK: FreeText could be anything really like Two, 2, Level 4,System Customer Location 2 etc.

Comment: @Charlieface: I like that idea. Of course it means I have to change my code and database, but at this point it won't have much impact. I will definitely give it some thought.